# SwiftUI Button Images showing up black

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, swiftui

I am trying to make a Button in SwiftUI show an image alongside the text. However, the image is showing up black even though it shows up when not in a button. What edits to my code do I need to add so that the image displays properly.

Here is what my code is currently:

```swift
List{
    Button(action: {
        self.changeAppIcon("AlternateIcon5")
    }) {
        HStack {
            Image("AlternateIcon5")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
            Text("Navy Blue")
        }
    }


    HStack {
        Image("AlternateIcon5")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
        Text("Test")
    }
}
```

Here is what it shows up as:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you add the modifier  `.renderingMode(.original)` to your images?

Comment: ```.renderingMode(.original)``` does not show up on the list of modifiers for the image and when I try to add it manually, it produces errors farther up in the code.

Comment: That is strange because it is a modifier for Image. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-disable-the-overlay-color-for-images-inside-button-and-navigationlink

Comment: Can I see the original image?

Comment: I was able to get it to work. The problem was (I think) that I had it as the last modifier for the image but when it was the first one it worked. Thank you very much for your help Andrew.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Without Code:

1. Go to `Assets.xcassets` from the project navigator and **select your image** there.
2. From the right panel, **Attributes Inspector**
3. Select `Original Image` for **Render As**

[image: Inspector]

**Remember** you should always do this for all images that you don't want to apply any color on them.

---

## With Code:

add this modifier to your `Image`:

```
.renderingMode(.original)
```

**Note that** it should be **right after the `Image`** itself (**NOT** after other modifiers like `cornerRadius`)

Comment: Thanks. I’m working only on the iPad, so the “with code:” is the solution. But really, Apple, why isn’t this the default?! If I wanted my image to be badly rendered, I should have the option to declare ```.renderingMode(.badlyMangled)```

Answer (score 5):

Please add the `.renderingMode(.original)` right after the Image().

```
    List{
    Button(action: {
        self.changeAppIcon("AlternateIcon5")
    }) {
        HStack {
            Image("AlternateIcon5")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
            Text("Navy Blue")
        }
    }


    HStack {
        Image("AlternateIcon5")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
        Text("Test")
    }
}
```